# Prevent IIS from killing a Task before it ends - Part 2

Tags: multithreading, iis, azure, threadpool

This is a continuation of

[Prevent IIS from killing a Task before it ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12665536/prevent-iis-from-killing-a-task-before-it-ends)

My question:

Given

```
public static Task StartNew(Action act)
{
    IISNotifier notif = new IISNotifier(); -> HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject(this);
    notif.Started();
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        act.Invoke();
        notif.Finished(); ->  HostingEnvironment.UnregisterObject(this);
    });
}
```

Invoked by

```
    return new LogResult(id, IISTaskFactory.StartNew(() => 
        DoLogInAzure(account, id, exception, request))
    );
```

Example implementation

```
    DoLogInAzure(account, id, exception, request)) {

            DoSomeLongOperation()
            **Thread.Yield()**
             DoLogInAzure();

    }
```

The above is just example code.  To illustrate Thread.Yield statement Ive made it recursive.

Question
Please bear in mind this is running in a Azure web role or potentially an Azure website.
1.) What does the Thread.Yield() statement actually do in the context of IIS in the above example?
1a.) I would assume it would allow the thread to service other incoming requests
1b.) Would it allow IIS to tear down the thread i.e. would the recursion stop?

Many thanks, especially to Gervasio Marchand, Damian Schenkelman and that blog post of Phil Haack and to you too if you can answer it :)

Comment: Why are you using `Yield` in the first place? This does not seem to be useful.