# Why would Task.Factory.StartNew() never run its action under IIS7?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, taskfactory

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 IIS 7 instance running .ASP.NET WebForms .NET 4.0 code.  In a postback there is a thread spawn that runs a long-running process.

The below code does not work under IIS7.  It works fine locally under Cassini and on another Windows Server 2003 IIS6 instance we have available.

```
var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessWorkItem(wid));
var ex = t.Exception;
Log(string.Format("Spawned background task to wid={5}: id={1} status={4} isfaulted={3} iscompleted={2} ex={0}",
            ex == null ? "no exception" : ex.ToString(),
            t.Id,
            t.IsCompleted,
            t.IsFaulted,
            t.Status,
            wid));
```

This logs "no exception" and "isfaulted=false" and "iscompleted=true" regardless of server.

However, there is also a log statement inside the `ProcessWorkItem`, which is never hit on IIS7, though it is hit just fine on IIS6 or Cassini local dev server.

Any idea why that would be?

Comment: Where is the log file? IIS may not have the privilege to write to the local disk.

Comment: It actually logs to the system eventlog.  The user running IIS has access to the event log.

Comment: ProcessWorkItem was run. It just has a bug.

Comment: @usr: I thought that too, but I can't substantiate it in any way.  The first thing in the action is Log(...) and I never see that.  Maybe I can try throwing an exception instead... see what that does...

Comment: I had similar issue, once deployed, it method was not getting called. Parameters to method turned out to be the issue. I encapsulated parameters into internal class & it started working.

Comment: @SamJackSon: Can you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: Please take a look at this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12665536/prevent-iis-from-killing-a-task-before-it-ends